# Is a tiny dent in a compressor tank a safety concern?

Tags: compressor, air-compressor

I saw some questions and answers on air compressors so I thought I would ask one: I just purchased a Chicago Pneumatics 21 gallon compressor and I noticed a tiny dent about 3+ inches from the upper seam, (almost unnoticeable, like the edge of something hit it or the tank fell on it). Again, it is really shallow, but is this something to worry over?

Comment: And it's *Chicago* Pneumatic?  I ask because CP is a top-shelf supplier to industry, oil rigs, factories etc. at par with Ingersoll-Rand.   I find it a bit surprising that a CP dealer would let a dinged unit out of their shop.   Reason I ask is that certain purveyors of Cheese junk love to use confusingly similar brand names, such as Central Pneumatic, which is a house brand of Harbor Freight.

Answer (score 1):

As the reservoir for an air compressor holds air under pressure, the forces on the dent will be outward. If the dent is not on a seam or other metal discontinuity, and is shallow enough, little will happen. When it is pressurized the first time, if it does not "un-dent" itself, you likely have little about which to worry. Even if it does pop out, it won't go beyond flush and again, no worry.

Keep an eye on the dent. If the paint is scratched and the metal under begins to rust, not so good. If the paint is cracked or scratched, consider to apply primer and topcoat to remove future rust problems.

Rust is a problem over long periods of time, especially on the inside, so drain your tank frequently and examine it for outside rust and damage as well.

Comment: I would be afraid to use the tank if it pops back out. If the paint was not damaged the dent may have been there prior to being finished, pressure tanks are tested to 5/3 working pressure and on low pressure tanks they are usually much stronger than this value.